# How do I iterate and visit each link in a list using selenium and python? How do I click on each link on a Yelp page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would love to visit each link on this yelp page that has Dumpling included in the link text.

[Picture of List of Links on yelp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26UKM.jpg)

Here is the code. I got to the second page but not sure on how to click into each link. I want each link to open in a new. but only dumpling ones. Thank you. Hope this makes sense.

```
all_links = []

#yelp page
driver.get("https://yelp.com");

#Selecting the first box
 type_of_food = driver.find_element_by_id('find_desc')

#Enter Chinese Food
type_of_food.send_keys('Chinese Food');

#press enter
type_of_food.send_keys(Keys.ENTER);


driver.implicitly_wait(30)
#Button click

driver.find_element_by_id("header-search-submit").click()


driver.implicitly_wait(9)



driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Dumpling')

for link in all_links:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: ` I want each link to open in a new.` What does this mean? Do you want to open each link in a new window?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if your code is all correct.

A. You have typed `Chinese Food` in the search area, then keying in `ENTER`, then again clicking on `Search` button. But only one of them would do. Both doesn't seem to be required.

B. `for link in all_links:` I do not understand why you are trying to loop through a declared blank list (list declared on top: `all_links = []`). It does not have anything in it. Assuming that you are trying to link through the dumpling elements, I have refactored your code to below:

```
all_links = []
#yelp page
driver.get("https://yelp.com")
#Selecting the first box
type_of_food = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'find_desc')
#Enter Chinese Food
type_of_food.send_keys('Chinese Food')
#press enter
# type_of_food.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
#Button click
driver.find_element(By.ID, "header-search-submit").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(9)
dumplings = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Dumpling')
for item in dumplings:
    all_links.append(item.get_attribute('href'))
    # Replace CONTROL with COMMAND if you are on Mac
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(item).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    

print(all_links)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.yelp.com/biz/dumpling-kitchen-san-francisco?osq=Chinese+Food', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/dumpling-house-san-francisco?osq=Chinese+Food', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/dumpling-baby-china-bistro-san-francisco-4?osq=Chinese+Food', 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Dumplings&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you! Your Amazing! I also would like all of them open up in different tabs. Is that possible?

Comment: @gabi145, added line in my answer. Please check the last line, it should work. Also, if the answer works for you, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(30) Might want to switch over for webdriver waits.

Comment: I wanted to upvote you. but i didn't have enough points. I only needed four more so I posted another question to try and get help. But someone downvoted another question of mine. For not upvoting you here. My account won't let me upvote? Thank you though. I will upvote when I get enough points Thank you for your help.  @AnandGautam

Comment: Why switch over @ArundeepChohan.

Comment: @gabi145, Explicit Wait is advantageous over implicit, for you can make your driver wait for the desired reasons. For instance, implicit wait would make the driver wait until the element is present in the DOM, but with explicit wait like WedriverWait, you may make the driver wait for either presence of element,  or visibility of element, or wait until the element becomes clickable, etc. Refer [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-differences-between-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium-with-python) for more details

Comment: Wow. Thank you @AnandGautam. Thank you for teaching me this. I didn't understand the real difference. But now I'm starting to understand. :)